# (XSLT) how to sum elements from multi-occurence structure , with condition from different multi-occurance structure

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have two multi-occurrence structures `<first>` and `<second>`. They have the same number.(it means e.g. 3 elements `<first>` and 3 elements`<second>`). I need to create one sum , but with following conditions:
 `sum(if( first/code=second/code and first/boolean='TRUE')then val1*val2))`

**Input XML:**

```
<test>
    <first>
        <code>1</code>
        <booleanV>TRUE</booleanV>
    </first>
    <first>
        <code>2</code>
        <booleanV>FALSE</booleanV>
    </first>
    <first>
        <code>3</code>
        <booleanV>TRUE</booleanV>
    </first>
    <second>
        <code>1</code>
        <val1>2</val1>
        <val2>3</val2>
    </second>
    <second>
        <code>2</code>
        <val1>4</val1>
        <val2>5</val2>
    </second>
    <second>
        <code>3</code>
        <val1>6</val1>
        <val2>7</val2>
    </second>
</test>
```

In my case, result will be:
`sum(2*3+6*7).`

Can anyone assist me how to do above requirement using XSLT?

Comment: Please state if using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: In my case :XSLT 1.0

Comment: Please add tag of XSLT 1.0 rather than XSLT.

Comment: @umarfaraz The `xslt-1.0` tag should be **added** to the `xslt` tag, not replace it.

Comment: I am sorry about it, @ Michael.hor257k. I would surely never do this mistake again.

Answer (score 2):

In XSLT 1.0, you need to do this in two steps:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="first" match="first" use="code"/>

<xsl:template match="/test">
    <!-- first-pass -->
    <xsl:variable name="products">
        <xsl:for-each select="second[key('first', code)/booleanV = 'TRUE']">
            <product>
                <xsl:value-of select="val1 * val2"/>
            </product>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output -->
    <result>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(exsl:node-set($products)/product)"/>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to use XSLT 2.0, you can create a key of `first` elements that have a `booleanV` equal to `TRUE` and then loop over the `second` elements that match the key...

**XML Input**

```
<test>
    <first>
        <code>1</code>
        <booleanV>TRUE</booleanV>
    </first>
    <first>
        <code>2</code>
        <booleanV>FALSE</booleanV>
    </first>
    <first>
        <code>3</code>
        <booleanV>TRUE</booleanV>
    </first>
    <second>
        <code>1</code>
        <val1>2</val1>
        <val2>3</val2>
    </second>
    <second>
        <code>2</code>
        <val1>4</val1>
        <val2>5</val2>
    </second>
    <second>
        <code>3</code>
        <val1>6</val1>
        <val2>7</val2>
    </second>
</test>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="firsts" match="first[booleanV='TRUE']" use="code"/>

  <xsl:template match="test">
    <results>
      <xsl:value-of select=
        "sum(
             for $x in second[key('firsts',code)] 
               return $x/val1 * $x/val2
             )"/>
    </results>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<results>48</results>
```